# How to manage session in Node.js

Tags: session, node.js, express

I'm using express.session and connect-mongo be my DataStore.

What I'm facing is... in my server, I have 20 different app.get() calls. but not all of them require to check the session.

however, if i do this in the beginning of my server:

```
express.createServer( express.session({ ... }));
```

Then every single call will trigger the express.session and thus, set a session to mongoDB.

How to I limit to only the ones I want to trigger express.session?

```
e.g. app.get('/getASession')  will get a session
app.get('/donotGetSession')  will not even trigger express.session
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out the solution.  express.session return as a function. so I can do this:

```
global.mySession = express.session({ secret: session_secret,
    store:new MongoStore({  
        db: session_db_name,
        host: session_db_ip,
        port: session_db_port
    })
});



app.get('/checkSession', mySession, function (req, res) {
    res.send("<div>ok</div>");
});
```

so, if I don't want soemthing use session, then i don't put mySession there. :)  simple. i love node. :D

Comment: That is really a feature of express.js not node but I do agree. I love them both.